# Need help optimizing jQuery function (hover effect)

Tags: jquery, html, css, optimization, hover

I have a made a custom hover effect with jQuery. But it doesn't always runs that smooth. I want to use it often on multiple buttons and div's. I'm not that pro with jQuery so I think this code can be more efficient and more clean.

What it does, it creates two div's which are transformed into half a square (triangle) by CSS (clip-path). these two triangles get the `outerWidth()` and `outherHeight()` of the element that you hover. The triangles are positioned outside the hovered element so they can slide in. When you hover out the triangles will slide out and will then be deleted. The `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` will then be reset.

I have put it on jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/6uuh0ha7/5/

HTML

```
<div class="effect position">
```

CSS

```
    .position{
            left: 100px;
            top: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid 1px;
    }

    .effect .first {
           opacity: 0;
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-size: cover;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }


    .effect:hover .first {
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-size: cover;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    }

    .effect .second {
           opacity: 0;
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-size: cover;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    }

    .effect:hover .second {
           /*opacity: 1;*/
           width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-size: cover;
           -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
           clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    }

    .effect {
           overflow: hidden;
           position: relative;
           text-align: center;
           cursor: default;
    }

    .effect .mask{
           position: absolute;
           overflow: hidden;
           top: 0;
           left: 0;
    }
```

Jquery

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $( ".effect" ).hover( function() {
            $(".first", this).finish();
            $(".second", this).finish();

            $colorRed = "#ff0000";
            $colorDarkRed = "#930000";

            $(this).append('<div class="mask first temp" style="background-color:' + $colorRed + ';"></div>');
            $(this).append('<div class="mask second temp" style="background-color:' + $colorDarkRed + ';"></div>');


            $width  = $(this).outerWidth() + 'px';
            $height = $(this).outerHeight() + 'px';

            $( ".first", this ).css({"left" : $width, "top" : $height});
            $( ".second", this ).css({"left" : "-" + $width, "top" : "-" + $height});


            $( ".first", this ).css({"opacity" : "1"});
            $( ".second", this ).css({"opacity" : "1"});

            $( ".first", this ).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                top: "-0",
                left: "-0"
            }, 200, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });

            $( ".second", this ).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({
                top: "+0",
                left: "+0"
            }, 200, function() {
                // Animation complete.
            });

        },
        function() {            
            $( ".first", this ).animate({
                top: "+" + $height,
                left: "+" + $width
            }, 200, function() {
                $( ".first", this ).css({"opacity" : "0"});
            });

            $( ".second", this ).animate({
                top: "-" + $height,
                left: "-" + $width
            }, 200, function() {
                $( ".second", this ).css({"opacity" : "0"});
            });

        $('.temp').animate({opacity: 0 },
            'fast', // how fast we are animating
            'linear', // the type of easing
        function() { // the callback
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $width = undefined;
        $height = undefined;
    });

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the jsfiddle does nothing. only white

Comment: "Optimisation" is something you might get help with at [**CodeReviewe**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but check their guidlelines before posting. This is question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I checked it before I uploaded this question but something went wrong. I had put in CSS comments with //. A mistake. I fixed it now tough.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just add css with `.effect` class i.e.

```
.effect{
  min-height:100px
}
```